# MongoDB - How to delete expired documents except last one

Tags: mongodb

We're working on audit log solution for one of our projects and would appreciate your help.

We have media entity which contains media id (numeric), action (string, eg. PUBLISH) and occurred on date with time representing date and time when action happened.

Requirement is to delete logs that are older than 90 days but to keep log with last action on media entity.

We are using `Mongo 3.2` and we need help how to organize our collection since we need to support reads and writes on collection that will contain 200-300 millions of documents.

We tried several approaches but couldn't figure out a simple way on how to do it.

**First approach**

We tried to solve it with flat collection with document format:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("570b3cf65eac4e48e92b4e20"),
  mediaId: 10000,
  action: "PUBLISH",
  occurredOn: ISODate("2016-04-04T12:42:07.000Z")
}
```

where insert is easy but we have problem with deletion of documents.

**Second approach**

We also tried to solve it with documents that contain array of actions and dates:

```
{
  _id: 10000,
  actions: [
    {
      action:"PUBLISH", 
      occurredOn: ISODate("2016-04-04T12:42:07.000Z")
    }, 
    ...
  ]
}
```

where insert is also easy but again we have problem with deletion of documents.

Any suggestions on how to organize schema for this scenario?

Comment: `occuredOn` is an ISODate, I assume?

Comment: Is there a requirement to keep both recent and last logs in the same collection? Splitting it by 2 collections makes it trivial to maintain, but may be a bit more expensive to query.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg it is ISODate.

Comment: @AlexBlex Generally that is a good idea but we dropped it since we cannot
have atomicity with two writes. There is a possibility to have inconsistent data in second collection.

Comment: I thought about writing to the second collection (_id: mediaId) right before removing expired data from the main log, not on every insert - it would be overkill. In any case you select  `occurredOn` > 90 days from the second collection. In worst-case scenario (previous  log entry was exactly 90 days ago) it just gives you 1 extra log entry per `mediaId` in addition to today's entries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, it is pretty simple though not to be done in a single query.

## Non-matched data

Let us say we have a collection which stores the values for a single mediaId first, as this makes the approach a bit more clear.

### Sample data

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570ba4f66931b8f21a8bf25f"), "a" : 3, "date" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570ba50a6931b8f21a8bf260"), "a" : 4, "date" : ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570baab36931b8f21a8bf261"), "a" : 5, "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
```

Note that all dates are more than 90 days in the past as of the time of this writing.

### The procedure

First, we want to identify the `_id` of the last entry, which we want to keep no matter what:

```
> db.date.find({},{_id:1}).sort({date:-1}).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570ba4f66931b8f21a8bf25f") }
```

Next, we want to delete all entries which are older than 90 days and are not the last entry:

```
var outdated = new Date()
outdated.setDate(outdated.getDate() - 90 )
// We check first
db.date.find({
    _id:{ $not:{ $eq: ObjectId("570ba4f66931b8f21a8bf25f") }},
    date:{ $lt: outdated }
})
```

Which gives us the correct documents:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570ba50a6931b8f21a8bf260"), "a" : 4, "date" : ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570baab36931b8f21a8bf261"), "a" : 5, "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
```

So we can run

```
> db.date.remove({
    _id:{ $not:{ $eq: ObjectId("570ba4f66931b8f21a8bf25f") }},
    date:{ $lt: outdated }
})
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 2 })
> db.date.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570ba4f66931b8f21a8bf25f"), "a" : 3, "date" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
```

### Why does this work?

Simple logic. Unless stated otherwise, the query conditions are conjuncted with a logical AND, meaning all conditions must be met for a document to match. So even if the last document is older than 90 days, it is excluded by the `$not` phrase.

## Multiple mediaIds

Now, we get to the real stuff.

### Sample data

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570baf826931b8f21a8bf262"), "mediaId" : 1000, "date" : ISODate("2016-04-11T14:06:58.668Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570baf8e6931b8f21a8bf263"), "mediaId" : 1000, "date" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570bafa06931b8f21a8bf264"), "mediaId" : 1001, "date" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570bafa56931b8f21a8bf265"), "mediaId" : 1001, "date" : ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570bafc96931b8f21a8bf266"), "mediaId" : 1002, "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570bafcd6931b8f21a8bf267"), "mediaId" : 1002, "date" : ISODate("2013-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
```

### Identify last documents

We have to use an aggregation here:

```
db.media.aggregate(
    { $sort:{ date:1 }},
    { $group:{
         _id:"$mediaId",
         lastId:{ "$last":"$_id" },
    }},
    { $group:{
      _id:"lastIds",
      ids:{ $push:"$lastId" }
    }},
    { $project:{ _id: 0, ids: 1 } }
)
```

Let us dissect that:

1. `{ $sort:{ date:1 }}` We want to have all sorted ascending
2. `{$group:{_id:"$mediaId",lastId:{"$last":"$_id"}}}` We want the last ObjectId in sort order for each `mediaId`
3. `{ $group:{ _id:"lastIds", ids:{ $push:"$lastId" } }}` we want to have all ObjectIds in an array and us an artificial static `_id` to make sure all ObjectIds are pushed to said array.
4. `{ $project:{ _id: 0, ids: 1 } }` And we want only said array to be returned

The result is

```
{
    "ids" : [
        ObjectId("570baf826931b8f21a8bf262"),
        ObjectId("570bafa06931b8f21a8bf264"),
        ObjectId("570bafc96931b8f21a8bf266")
     ]
 }
```

Those are the ObjectIds we definetly want to keep.

You use those for

### Removing the old docs

#### Using `$in`

```
db.media.find({
    _id:{ $not:{ $in:[
        ObjectId("570baf826931b8f21a8bf262"),
        ObjectId("570bafa06931b8f21a8bf264"), 
        ObjectId("570bafc96931b8f21a8bf266")
    ]}},
    date:{$lt: outdated}
})
```

The problem here is that `$in` is not exactly good performing for (admittedly rather large) arrays. It might be sufficient for you, since the removal does not exactly seem to be time critical. However, you can also remove the docs by

#### Using bulk operations

We adjust the identification of the last docs a bit and add a bulk operation for each of the documents we want to keep:

```
var bulk = db.media.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
db.media.aggregate(
    { $sort:{ date: 1 } },
    { $group:{  _id: "$mediaId", lastId:{ "$last": "$_id" }}}
).forEach(
    function(doc){
        bulk.find({
          _id:{ $not:{ $eq: doc.lastId }},
          date:{ $lt: outdated }
        }).remove()
    }
)
bulk.execute()
```

This method is as easy as it may get, imho, while retaining decent performance.

Comment: Thank you on answer. We will try bulk operations since $in will not work very well with array of 200-300 million ids. Is `mediaId` condition missing in bulk.find query and should date condition be `{$gt: outdated}`?

Comment: @jgrgurica We `$group`ed all documents by `mediaId` and just took the `_id` of the last one. So for all existing `mediaId`s, we have the `_id` of the last document, which we do not want to be deleted. Hence, we exclude said `_id`s. And `$lt` is correct, too, since time is increasing monotonically (relativity theory aside). Think of UNIX epoch.